# Можно ли приватные переменные использовать в классе наследнике? java

Tags: java, ооп

Есть класс Enemy в нем есть переменные name, healthPoint и damage. У всех этих переменных стоит модификатор приватности private. Есть еще один класс Zombie он наследует класс Enemy. Как можно в классе Zombie использовать приватные переменные из класса Enemy помимо геттеров и сеттеров?

```
public class Enemy {
     private String name;
     private int healthPoint=10, damage=1;
     public void setName(String nameIn){
        name=nameIn;
     }
}
```

Comment: через конструктор, если вы его добавите в суперкласс. иначе никак (рефлексия и прочие танцы с бубном не в счет), ведь именно в этом и смысл приватных полей. и на самом деле вам это не надо.

Comment: @Дмитрий Spring передает привет :)

Comment: @Митяй причем тут сприрнг? так или иначе конструктор суперкласса должен быть вызван. это требование не спринга. таким образом, даже если ваш класс-наследник является бином, то никаких проблем не возникает. инициализируйтесь с помощью конструктора, что вполне умеет делать спринг, и будет вам счастье.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

что-то вроде такого

```
public class Enemy {
     private String name;
     private int healthPoint=10, damage=1;

     public void setName(String nameIn){
        this.name=nameIn;
     }

   public String getName(){
     return name;
   }
}
```

```
public class Zombie extends Enemy{

    private void test(){
        Log.d("TEST", getName());
    }
    
}
```

Comment: Вопрос был `помимо геттеров и сеттеров`